# How can I root my Xolo Q1010i?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting

I have tried kingoroot, Towel Root, Framaroot as well as WMShua to root Xolo Q1010i but at last stage the message "Sorry Root Failed" appears.

Kernel version : 3.4.67

Please provide me with other ways.

Comment: It appears that the mentioned Root apps are unable to find a working exploit as I noted bellow, I think you will have more luck with rooting your device if you flashed a different ROM on it. (pre-rooted if possible).

Comment: Nup it didn't work..whenever I try to flash with different ROM,in fastboot mode it says that your phone didn't support flash..now what to do..

Comment: Okay, did you try [this](http://www.unlock-bootloader.info/mp3-0/xolo-q1010i-6275.html) yet?

Comment: Okay will let u know if it works...thanks @Jordy..

Comment: Hello @Jordy..Thanks for your help.I have rooted my device.

Comment: Great to hear, enjoy your rooted device!

Comment: @GulamMohammed As you succeeded, may I ask you to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)? There's [another user in need](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/110033/16575) who would profit from it. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Successful attempt, here's the complete step-by-step procedure of rooting Xolo Q1010i.

---

**Root Xolo Q1010i Using Kingroot Android App**

---

- Download and install KingMaster, Kingroot and Kinguser android application from [official website](http://www.kingroot.net/down). The website is in Chinese language, but you can easily download using blue download buttons.
- Open Kingroot android app and click on green round button. Your device may restart.
- Now open KingMaster application from app drawer, you will get a pull down window! Click on root now button. You can also [watch video for the same](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dF_NOQU9Cmc).
- After few minutes KingMaster will root your Xolo Q1010i **without** KitKat update.

---

**Root Xolo Q1010i By Flashing Pre- Rooted Android 4.4.2 KitKat Stock ROM**

---

- Framaroot will not work on our Xolo Q1010i after KitKat update. If you have stock Jelly Bean then you should use Framaroot method.
- If not then, First we need to flash custom recovery on our Xolo Q1010i in-order to flash Pre-Rooted stock ROM.

**Downloads:**

---

- [MTK USB Drivers](http://ge.tt/7nbYNYy/v/0) (Driver_Auto_Installer, 9.2 MB)
- [MT6582 Scatter File](http://d-h.st/aWU) (500 KB)
- [CTR Recovery for Q1010i Only](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzOdJOMrMdywU2IwWmVtQlpNM00/view) (6 MB)
- [SP Flash Tools v3.1352.01 (5.1352.01)](http://d-h.st/w6v) (23 MB)
- [SuperSu Zip](https://download.chainfire.eu/451/SuperSU/UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.01.zip) (2 MB)

**Rooting Instructions**

---

- Download and extract all files. Place all Downloaded Files in the same place for easy access. I recommend you to turn off your antivirus to avoid permission related issues.

[image: Step 1]

- Install The MTK USB Drivers on Your PC by Clicking on Install.bat in Driver_Auto_Installer_v1.1236.00 folder.
- Open SP Flash Tools folder and click on flash_tool.exe.  In The Flash Tool window Click on Scatter-Loading, Select MT6582_Android_scatter_emmc.txt and Press Open.

[image: Step 2]

- In Flash Tool Window Tick **RECOVERY** and Click on the Blank Green Space Beside It and select recovery.img.

[image: Step 3]

- Switch Off Your Device and Connect it to your PC. Now press on green download button at the top.
- The status bar at the bottom will Change it’s Color Red Then Yellow and Finally show a Download OK Dialog Box.
- Now disconnect your phone and close SP Flash tool.
- Press and Hold Volume UP and Power Button Together till it powers UP.
- Now your phone boots into Recovery Mode, In it Press Install Zip -> Choose Zip SDCard -> Select the SuperSu.zip You Placed Earlier in Your SDCard and Press YES to Install.
- On Complete Installation, Reboot Your Device, CONGRATULATIONS ! You’ve Successfully Flashed carliv recovery on your device!

**So now we need to flash Pre- Rooted Android 4.4.2 KitKat ROM into our Xolo Q1010i smartphone.**

- Download [Pre-Rooted Flashable Zip of Stock Android 4.4.2 KitKat ROM](http://d-h.st/5qB).
- Place SuperSu Zip (downloaded in first step) and Pre- Rooted KitKat in your SD Card.
- Goto Recovery Mode, Go To Install -> Install from SD -> Select the ROM File and press YES to Flash it and Do the Same for the SuperSu Zip after Flashing completes.
- Reboot, now you successfully flashed Pre- Rooted Android 4.4.2 KitKat Stock ROM on your Xolo Q1010i.

***In other words, now you have successfully rooted your Xolo Q1010i with Android 4.4.2 KitKat update.***

**Source** : [Brief-Tutorials](http://brieftutorials.com/how-to-root-xolo-q1010i-kitkat-android-4-4-2/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gulam – also in the name of the "other user in need", who lacks the rep to comment here. Quoting him: *Before I could read your reply, I rooted my phone through iroot. It got stuck in the first attempt. In the second attempt it rooted but did not install any superuser. I downloaded supersu and installed it. Also checked thru rootchecker. Its working fine. Thanks for all the help.* Guess that means I should also upvote for him :)

Comment: Anytime @Izzy..:)

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the mentioned Root apps are unable to find a working exploit for your device.
Did you try [Towel Root](https://towelroot.com/) yet?

Comment: I have tried it and it says that "This phone isn't currently supported".

Comment: Can u provide me some other ways @Jordy19 and thanks for the Towel Root...

Comment: Yes there are more Root apps. Please tell me which version of Android you use.

Comment: M currently using android 4.4.2...

Comment: Can u please help me @Jordy19

Comment: I suggest flashing a different ROM on your device and then you can root it.

Comment: Okay will let you know after trying with different ROM...thanks @Jordy19

Comment: I have tried flashing ROM but in fastboot mode message "phone doesn't support flash" appears...now what to do..

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2746379).

Comment: Hello @Jordy...I go through the link u described but it needs a rooted device for that and the first line in that has a link providing "How to root Xolo Q1010i"...In that they used framaroot..I have also tried it but it didn't work as I mentioned earlier..

Comment: Thanks for the help man..please suggest me other ways because I want to root my phone by any ways...

Answer (score 2):

[Here is the info](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2715830) I have found on [how to do this](http://androidxda.com/root-xolo-q1010i):

- Download and install [Framaroot](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/framaroot/root-framaroot-one-click-apk-to-root-t2130276) ([donation app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alephzain.framarootdonation2))
- Open the application
- Select "Install SuperSU"
  [image]
- Click on Barahir
  [image]
- You will now see a popup. Reboot your device now and you are rooted
  [image]

Comment: I have tried it but it says exploit error...

Comment: Any other way to root @Ryan Conrad..