# My OS Loads, but no Recovery

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, adb, fastboot, huawei

- Handset: Huawei Honor Holly
- Root: Yes

---

I am trying to install CWM recovery on this phone. I tried it using [Flashify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cgollner.flashify&hl=en) after reading guidelines from a website. Now, my stock recovery is gone. Also, fastboot commands wont work.

```
fastboot erase recovery
erasing 'recovery'... // And stops here. No progress for hours
```

When I try `adb reboot recovery`, my phone restarts again after displaying a black screen.

How do I install CWM, or TWRP, or get back to Stock Recovery?

Comment: This device has mt6582 chipset which is supported by **SP Flash Tool**. You can use this tool to flash your recovery rather easily. See **Method #2** in my answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/109337/96277) for *know-how* of this tool, if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to flash twrp or CWM via fastboot without the use of the `fastboot erase recovery` as that got rid of it. Fastboot should just overwrite it anyway. Download links are in the blog post :
[CWM/TWRP Recovery Club](http://www.cwm-twrp-recovery.club/mp3-0/huawei-honor-holly-6738.html)

but instead just use `fastboot flash recovery <your_recovery_image_file_here>` and it should work.

**Edit:** A nice guide is up on the [XDA Forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/guide-huawei-honor-holly-stock-rom-t3031466) and tells you all the tools you need

Comment: `fastboot flash recovery recovery.img`
`sending 'recovery' (6370 KB)...`
`OKAY [  0.204s]`
`writing 'recovery'...`
`FAILED (remote:`
`partition 'recovery' not support flash)`
`finished. total time: 0.220s`

Comment: @KarthikVU See this [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/79480/96277) for your commented error.